# Django queryset not returning data

Tags: python, django

I am trying to return only the notes of the currently logged in user. Here is my

```
  def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Note.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    return qs
```

This returns nothing. However:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Note.objects.all()
    return qs
```

Returns everything.

I have tried every thing just to return the notes of the logged in user, so maybe queryset is not the right solution. My question is two fold:

What is the best way to return the notes of the logged in user.
If it is query set, what is the best way to form the queryset.

thank you.

**MODEL**

```
User = get_user_model()

class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    text_html = models.TextField(editable=False, default='', blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**Views**

```
class NoteList(ListView):
    model = Note


    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Note.objects.select_related().filter(user=self.request.user)
        return qs
```

Comment: What is `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: I do not have that in my settings file, what is it?

Comment: `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,default=1)`

Comment: OH I see, do you have any idea what it should be, as you can tell I copied this from an example.

Comment: if you want to use your own user model, `AUTH_USER_MODEL ` should point to your UserModel. Otherwise, the foreignkey must be: `user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), default=1)`

Comment: Next time tell that you borrowed example code. It surely will be the name of the user model, but try replacing it with `User` (and make an import at the top `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`).

Comment: Thanks, Juan,  I tried the modification, but with no joy. I even tried migrating the database again but it saw nothing to migrate. Thanks for you idea though.